# Blank screen on boot after upgrade from 9.04 to 10.04 with a toshiba tecra a2. Fix?

Tags: video, boot, upgrade

I can boot into recovery via grub and the low graphics mode option works but I don't really know what to do from there to fix it so I can use a proper graphics mode. It is usuable now though some colours are missing.

According to wikipedia the Tecra A2 has 16-64 MB DDR RAM Intel graphic adapter. If that is worth anything. In Windows these are driver details listed in the video properties: Intel 82852/82855 GM/GME Graphics Controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These problem are usually seen in i8xx chips. Sadly ubuntu has not any proper solution for this. But they have published [potential fixes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/Lucidi8xxFreezes). Just hope one of them work for you.

Also check out this [post](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-ubuntu-10-04-lts-lucid-blank-screen-at-startup.html) on ubuntugeek.

Comment: Those are both good links.

Comment: The GTT Incoherency Patch worked but for those who come later it took two reboots to get it to work normally for some reason.

Comment: Actually, it is still pretty disappointing.  Every second boot there is no border or title bar for the windows and I am not getting full colour.  I'll probably just roll back to karmic because I only upgraded in hopes that they would have fixed the handling of projectors but failing to properly support my video chip makes that rather a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I tried everything I read on the web and nothing worked. Here is how I got my laptop working (New Dell E5510 with i5 Intel GMA HD Graphics).

- I had to (and it sounds like you already did) edit grub from a recovery console. This allowed me to actually boot up into a UI.
- Add the xorg-edgers PPA to your apt-sources: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates
- Update your kernel to 2.6.35-14 (kernel image is available in apt-get)
- Change your video driver to "intel" in your xorg.conf

Let me know if you need exact details on any of the steps. This took me about 3 days to figure out (I did multiple installs, tried multiple kernels, and used tonsof xorg configurations). The above is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: `i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa` boot options were enough for my Dell e5510. I have 64-bit Ubuntu 10.10.