# Blank screen after upgrading to 10.04 to 10.10

Tags: upgrade

I have upgraded my desktop to Lucid from karmic online through update manager - facing problems, request your help.

After completing upgrade and then reboot, I am getting blank screen. Tried to login but unsuccessful.

Also the data backup done pre-upgrade was partial, I donot want to lose data.
Request to please provide steps to rollback without losing data as I am new to ubuntu.
Also I have a single partition.
Graphics card is agp-8x integrated (hp d530)

Comment: And your graphics card is...?

Comment: hi
it is agp-8x integrated (hp d530)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Use Ctrl+Alt+F1 to switch to the first text terminal. Only Ctrl+Alt+F7 is the graphical one. Try `sudo service gdm stop` and `startx` to restore your desktop session.

Answer (score 2):

I used to have the same problem when upgrading to 10.10, to work around this is a bit of a pain but with the helpful Ubuntu-folks and tons of tutorials and step-by-step guide I got it to work.

Did you browse around other similar questions? Although it speaks about 10.04 and not 10.10, I think [Blank screen on boot after upgrade from 9.04 to 10.04 with a toshiba tecra a2. Fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2672/blank-screen-on-boot-after-upgrade-from-9-04-to-10-04-with-a-toshiba-tecra-a2-fi) or trather therein the link to the guide https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/Lucidi8xxFreezes might be what you are looking for aka get Ubuntu running to backup the missing data.

From the guide the following steps used to help me out:

From an existing installation:

1. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting to enter the GRUB menu.
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit.
3. Add `i915.modeset=1` after `quiet splash`.
4. <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd> to boot.

I hope this helps for the moment.

The aforementioned guide has even instructions on how to make this change permanent -- OR you could even upgrade to Natty 11.04.

Is there a reason why you didn't upgrade to 11.04 where this particular problem does not exist anymore (as far as I know). Or then why 10.10 and not stick with 10.04 that is a LTS (Long Term Support)?

And a final word for future upgrades: I would suggest you first try out new releases on a computer using the Live-CD, most problems might show up there.

I hope this rough start with Ubuntu does not turn you away from it.

Good luck
Andreas